# How to fix 'postgresql configuration' null' error in spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource

- I am using spring tool suite IDE for development.

**application.properties**

```
#Configuration
myconfig.source = "D:\\sourceFolder"

#Database configuration    
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Here is spring boot main application call

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo.class, args);
        ConfigProperties config = new ConfigProperties();
        System.out.println("get source folder path" + config.getSource()); // here Null
        DemoClass demo = new DemoClass();
        demo.process();
    }
}
```

Here is configuration class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myconfig")
public class ConfigProperties {
    //@Value("${myconfig.source}")
    private String source;

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }
    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }
}
```

Here is Demo class - process all data

```
public class DemoClass {
    @Autowired ConfigProperties config;
    @Autowired DataRepository repository;

    void process() {
        List<DemoData> getresultList = getList();
        System.out.println("get results List : " + getresultList);
    }

    private List<DemoData> getList() {
        System.out.println(" gettng all data from DB: " + repository.findAll());        
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Here table is

```
id | year | dataname | data
```

Here POJO class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "demodata")
public class DemoData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2343243243242432341L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "year")
    private int year;
    @Column(name = "dataname")
    private String dataName;
    @Column(name = "data")
    private String data;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getDataName() {
        return dataName;
    }

    public void setDataName(String dataName) {
        this.dataName = dataName;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }    
}
```

here JPA Repository

```
@Repository
public interface DataRepository extends JpaRepository<DemoData, Integer>{
    List<DemoData> findAll();
}
```

- Here am facing the issues are :

  1. get source folder path printing is **null**
  2. getting all data from DB: **null** exception

here my log

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2019-07-31 15:15:18.937  INFO 10720 --- [           main] c.e.filesCopy.DemoApplication       : Starting DemoApplication on Ashwath-PC with PID 10720 (D:\STS-workspace\xelpro\filesCopy\target\classes started by Ashwath in D:\STS-workspace\xelpro\filesCopy)
2019-07-31 15:15:18.944  INFO 10720 --- [           main] c.e.filesCopy.DemoApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-07-31 15:15:20.028  INFO 10720 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-07-31 15:15:20.137  INFO 10720 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 92ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-07-31 15:15:20.969  INFO 10720 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-07-31 15:15:21.409  INFO 10720 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-07-31 15:15:21.563  INFO 10720 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-07-31 15:15:21.663  INFO 10720 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2019-07-31 15:15:21.665  INFO 10720 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-07-31 15:15:21.887  INFO 10720 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-07-31 15:15:22.355  INFO 10720 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2019-07-31 15:15:23.457  INFO 10720 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@2d760326'
2019-07-31 15:15:23.462  INFO 10720 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-07-31 15:15:24.509  INFO 10720 --- [           main] c.e.filesCopy.DemoApplication       : Started DemoApplication in 6.23 seconds (JVM running for 6.919)
null
null gettng all data from DB: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.filesCopy.DemoData.getList(DemoData.java:33)
    at com.example.filesCopy.DemoData.process(DemoData.java:17)
    at com.example.filesCopy.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:19)
2019-07-31 15:15:24.525  INFO 10720 --- [       Thread-2] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-07-31 15:15:24.526  INFO 10720 --- [       Thread-2] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2019-07-31 15:15:24.545  INFO 10720 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-07-31 15:15:24.550  INFO 10720 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

**update is pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>filesCopy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>filesCopy</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: The ConfigProperties object should not be created with new. A plain Java object does't understand the spring configuration bound to it. It should be a Spring bean getting created by spring container. Use it as a bean with @Autowired, etc.

Comment: @grindlewald thanks for replay, still same null

Comment: i have updated, added my pom.xml file

Comment: Is the DemoClass a spring bean too? No class object should be explicitly created with new. Can you put updated code?

Comment: DemoClass like a controller, but i want run this app as .exe.. not from browser url